# How to append on existing field with elasticsearch python?

Tags: python-3.x, append, field, elasticsearch-5, kibana-5

I am using kibana and Elasticsearch version 5.1.1 and python version 3.6.

I have created my index like this 
[put_books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otlRZ.png)

**The function to add a user is this one** :

```
def add_user(first_name, last_name, age, mail):
    doc = {"first_name": "" + first_name, "last_name": "" + last_name, "age": age, "email": "" + mail}
    global id_user
    res = es.index(index="books", doc_type="user", id=id_user, body=doc)
    id_user += 1
    print(res['result'])
```

and to add preferences :

```
def add_preferences(preferences, i):
    doc = es.get(index="books", doc_type="user", id=id_book)
    res = es.update(index="books", doc_type="user", id=i, body={'doc':{"keyword_preferences": preferences}})
```

**My problem is here : when I want to add preferences, it success but if I want to add again preferences, it replace it** :

```
id_user = 1
nom = "nom_1"
prenom = "prenom_1"
age = 45
email = "adresse_mail_1"
add_user(prenom, nom, age, email)
add_preferences("comique", 1)
add_preferences("horreur", 1)
get_user(1)
```

the result is :

```
updated
{'first_name': 'prenom_1', 'last_name': 'nom_1', 'age': 45, 'email': 'adresse_mail_1', 'keyword_preferences': 'horreur'}
```

Finally, the solution was :

```
POST /books/user/1/_update
{
  "script" : {
    "inline": "ctx._source.keyword_preferences += params.preference",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params" : {
        "preference" : ["comique"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected result?

Comment: My expected result is : updated{'first_name': 'prenom_1', 'last_name': 'nom_1', 'age': 45, 'email': 'adresse_mail_1', 'keyword_preferences': {'comique', 'horreur'}}

Comment: You can't save keyword_preferences like above. You may save data in the list of dictionaries like `{ 'keyword_preferences': [{"preferences": "comique"},{"preferences": "horreur"}]}`.  For more info follow this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/array.html) .

Comment: I tried res = es.update(index="books", doc_type="user", id=i, body={'doc': {'keyword_preferences': [{"preferences" : preferences}]}})  but I have now : TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse [keyword_preferences]'    And when I modify the mapping it doesn't change

Comment: First, you need to create the mapping for `keyword_preferrences`.  then index into it.

Answer (score 2):

The new function is :

```
def add_preferences(preferences, i):
   doc = es.get(index="books", doc_type="user", id=i)
   res = es.update(index="books", doc_type="user", id=i, body={'doc': {'keyword_preferences': [{"preferences": preferences}]}})
```

The mapping is done and now I've got the result :

```
{'first_name': 'prenom_1', 'last_name': 'nom_1', 'age': 45, 'email': 'mail_1', 'keyword_preferences': [{'preferences': 'horreur'}]}
```

So, it has replaced the first preference "comique" by "horreur"

Answer (score 0):

Edited. example answer for your question.

Index a doc

```
POST /books/user/1
{
   "keyword_preferences": ["comique"]
}
```

Now, update a doc to append horreur in `keyword_preferences` key.

```
POST /books/user/1/_update
{
    "script": "ctx._source.keyword_preferences += keyword_preferences",
    "params": {
        "keyword_preferences": ["horreur"]
    },
    "lang": "groovy"
}
```

This will update keyword_preferences as ["comique", "horreur"].

If update API throws as exception `{"type":"script_exception","reason":"scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled"}`, then you need to config elasticsearch.yml. Add `script.engine.groovy.inline.update: on` `script.groovy.sandbox.enabled: true` in elasticsearch.yml and restart you elasticsearch. I hope this helps.

Comment: It works but still replace the first preference "comique" with "horreur"

Comment: Do you have an idea to append without replace ?